# RawQuery cannot compile: "Cannot figure out how to read this field from a cursor."

Tags: android-room

I've multiple `@RawQuery`s in my project with custom `data class`es as return type and this worked well so far, but now I'm trying to have a `data class` with a `List<OtherResult>` property and this fails at compile time with:

`error: Cannot figure out how to read this field from a cursor.`

So basically:

```
data class CustomResult(
    val count: Int,
    val name: String,
    val values: List<SubResult>,
)
data class SubResult(
    val sub_name: String,
    val sub_code: String,
)

------
Dao:

@RawQuery
abstract fun getCustomResultRaw(query: SimpleSQLiteQuery): List<CustomResult>

fun getCustomResult(): List<CustomResult> {
   val params = emptyArray<Any>()
   val query = "SELECT ..... "
   return getCustomResultRaw(SimpleSQLiteQuery(query, params))
}
```

Is there any way to force-tell room that the `List<>` property should be parsed as `SubResult`? What other options do I have?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to force-tell room that the List<> property should be parsed as SubResult?

No not like that. Room stores data in SQLite tables, that consist of columns and only a limited set of types those being, from an SQLite perspective:-

- NULL
- INTEGER (64 bit signed integer e.g. Long, Int, Byte ...)
- TEXT (character string e.g. String)
- REAL (8-byte IEEE floating point number e.g. Double, Float ...)
- BLOB (a stream of Bytes e.g. ByteArray)
- NUMERIC (any of the above **BUT not supported by ROOM**)

A column cannot directly contain multiple values such as a list.

> What other options do I have?

Basically two options:-

- Store the **SubResult** values in another table with a relationship to the **CustomResult**, this would be the way from a relational database perspective.

  - **CustomResult** would be the parent, **SubResult** would be the child (children)
- Store the **SubResults** as one of the allowable types (probably rules out INTEGER or REAL, rules out NULL), so you would need to Convert that data to either a ByteArray or a String. Typically the latter is used and the String is a JSON representation of the data. You then need to define TypeConverters to let ROOM know how to handle the conversion.

**Working Example**

The following is an example that uses both methods.

**NOTE** to cater for conversion of a list of SubResults the Google Gson library was added dependency `implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.9.0'` *(no need for this if using the second table with related SubResults)*

Here's the data classes:-

```
data class CustomResult(
    val count: Int,
    val name: String,
    /*val values: List<SubResult>, uses SubResultList to cater for Type Converters*/
    val values: SubResultList /* Not required if using table for SubResults */
)
data class SubResult(
    val sub_name: String,
    val sub_code: String,
)
/* Holder for List to suit conversion of SubResult List - Not needed if using table for SubResults*/
data class SubResultList(
    val srList: List<SubResult>
)
/* Primary Table for the CR's (as well as the converted list of SubResults)*/
@Entity
data class CRTable(
    @PrimaryKey
    val crId: Long?=null, /* Uniquely Identifies the CR Row - generated if null */
    @Embedded
    val customResult: CustomResult
)
/* Second table for the SR's - not needed if using JSON representation of SR List*/
@Entity
data class SRTable(
    @PrimaryKey
    val srId: Long?=null,
    @ColumnInfo(index = true)
    val parentCrId: Long,
    @Embedded
    val subResult: SubResult
)
/* For retrieving the CRTables WITH the related SRTable rows - not needed if using JSON representation of SR List*/
data class CRTableWithRelatedSRTables(
    @Embedded
    val crTable: CRTable,
    @Relation(entity = SRTable::class, parentColumn = "crId", entityColumn = "parentCrId")
    val srTableList: List<SRTable>
)
```

The Converters (2) to convert a SubResultList to JSON and back:-

```
class Converters {
    @TypeConverter
    fun convertSubResultListToJSONString(subResultList: SubResultList): String = Gson().toJson(subResultList)
    @TypeConverter
    fun convertJSONStringToSubResultList(jsonString: String): SubResultList = Gson().fromJson(jsonString,SubResultList::class.java)

}
```

The DAO interface (functions to access the database) :-

```
@Dao
interface AllDao {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    fun insert(crTable: CRTable): Long
    
    /* Not Needed if storing Subresults as an embedded list */
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    fun insert(srTable: SRTable): Long

    /* Query for embedded Subresults list */
    @Query("SELECT * FROM crtable")
    fun getAllCRTableRows(): List<CRTable>

    /* Query for both embedded Subresults (as they are combned in this example) and the related SRTable rows */
    @Transaction
    @Query("SELECT * FROM crtable")
    fun getAllCRTablesWithRelatedSRTables(): List<CRTableWithRelatedSRTables>
}
```

An @Database annotated class with a singleton for the instance. Note for brevity and convenience allows running on the main thread.

```
@TypeConverters(value = [Converters::class])
@Database(entities = [CRTable::class,SRTable::class], version = 1, exportSchema = false)
abstract class TheDatabase: RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun getAllDao(): AllDao

    companion object {
        private var instance: TheDatabase? = null
        fun getInstance(context: Context): TheDatabase {
            if (instance==null) {
                instance = Room.databaseBuilder(context,TheDatabase::class.java,"the_database.db")
                    .allowMainThreadQueries()
                    .build()
            }
            return instance as TheDatabase
        }
    }
}
```

- if using just the two tables, then @TypConverters would not need to be defined.
- if just embedding the SubResultsList then the SRTable class would not be included in the entities parameter

Finally putting it all together in an activity:-

```
const val TAG = "DBINFO"
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var db: TheDatabase
    lateinit var dao: AllDao
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        db = TheDatabase.getInstance(this)
        dao = db.getAllDao()
        
        /* Preapre some SubResults */
        val sr01 = SubResult("SR01","CODEA")
        val sr02 = SubResult("SR02","CODEB")
        val sr03 = SubResult("SR03","CODEC")
        val sr04 = SubResult("SR04","CODED")
        val sr05 = SubResult("SR05","CODEE")

        /* Prepare some SubResultLists */
        val srl1 = SubResultList(listOf(sr01,sr02,sr03))
        val srl2 = SubResultList(listOf(sr04,sr05))
        val srl3 = SubResultList(listOf(sr01,sr02,sr03,sr04,sr05))

        /* Add CustomResults for embedded SubresultList (i.e. converted to JSON)*/
        val cr01 = dao.insert(CRTable(customResult =  CustomResult(1,"CR01",srl1)))
        val cr02 = dao.insert(CRTable(customResult = CustomResult(2,"CR02",srl2)))
        val cr03 = dao.insert(CRTable(customResult = CustomResult(3,"CR03",srl3)))
        
        /* Add the related SRTable rows (each block is per parent CustomResult) */

        dao.insert(SRTable(null,cr01,sr01))
        dao.insert(SRTable(null,cr01,sr02))
        dao.insert(SRTable(null,cr01,sr03))

        dao.insert(SRTable(null,cr02,sr04))
        dao.insert(SRTable(null,cr02,sr05))

        dao.insert(SRTable(null,cr03,sr01))
        dao.insert(SRTable(null,cr03,sr02))
        dao.insert(SRTable(null,cr03,sr03))
        dao.insert(SRTable(null,cr03,sr04))
        dao.insert(SRTable(null,cr03,sr05))

        /* Extract and inspect the data (only need the more complex query as CRTable has the embedded SubResultsList) */
        for (crwsr in dao.getAllCRTablesWithRelatedSRTables()) {
            /* For each CRTable row */
            Log.d(TAG,"CRTable is ${crwsr.crTable.customResult.name} count is ${crwsr.crTable.customResult.count} it has ${crwsr.crTable.customResult.values.srList.size} SR's, it also has ${crwsr.srTableList.size} related SRTable rows.")
            Log.d(TAG,"SR's are:-")
            /* For each item in the SubResultList (for the current CustomResult) */
            for (sr in crwsr.crTable.customResult.values.srList) {
                Log.d(TAG,"\tSR is ${sr.sub_name} code is ${sr.sub_code}")
            }
            Log.d(TAG,"Related SR's are:-")
            /* For each related row in the SRTable (for the current CustomResult) */
            for (srt in crwsr.srTableList) {
                Log.d(TAG,"\tSR is ${srt.subResult.sub_name} code is ${srt.subResult.sub_code} ID is ${srt.srId} related to (child of) CR with an ID of ${srt.parentCrId}")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Results**

The log includes:-

```
2022-06-10 05:54:48.982 D/DBINFO: CRTable is CR01 count is 1 it has 3 SR's, it also has 3 related SRTable rows.
2022-06-10 05:54:48.982 D/DBINFO: SR's are:-
2022-06-10 05:54:48.982 D/DBINFO:   SR is SR01 code is CODEA
2022-06-10 05:54:48.982 D/DBINFO:   SR is SR02 code is CODEB
2022-06-10 05:54:48.982 D/DBINFO:   SR is SR03 code is CODEC
2022-06-10 05:54:48.982 D/DBINFO: Related SR's are:-
2022-06-10 05:54:48.982 D/DBINFO:   SR is SR01 code is CODEA ID is 1 related to (child of) CR with an ID of 1
2022-06-10 05:54:48.982 D/DBINFO:   SR is SR02 code is CODEB ID is 2 related to (child of) CR with an ID of 1
2022-06-10 05:54:48.982 D/DBINFO:   SR is SR03 code is CODEC ID is 3 related to (child of) CR with an ID of 1
2022-06-10 05:54:48.983 D/DBINFO: CRTable is CR02 count is 2 it has 2 SR's, it also has 2 related SRTable rows.
2022-06-10 05:54:48.983 D/DBINFO: SR's are:-
2022-06-10 05:54:48.983 D/DBINFO:   SR is SR04 code is CODED
2022-06-10 05:54:48.983 D/DBINFO:   SR is SR05 code is CODEE
2022-06-10 05:54:48.983 D/DBINFO: Related SR's are:-
2022-06-10 05:54:48.983 D/DBINFO:   SR is SR04 code is CODED ID is 4 related to (child of) CR with an ID of 2
2022-06-10 05:54:48.983 D/DBINFO:   SR is SR05 code is CODEE ID is 5 related to (child of) CR with an ID of 2
2022-06-10 05:54:48.983 D/DBINFO: CRTable is CR03 count is 3 it has 5 SR's, it also has 5 related SRTable rows.
2022-06-10 05:54:48.983 D/DBINFO: SR's are:-
2022-06-10 05:54:48.983 D/DBINFO:   SR is SR01 code is CODEA
2022-06-10 05:54:48.983 D/DBINFO:   SR is SR02 code is CODEB
2022-06-10 05:54:48.983 D/DBINFO:   SR is SR03 code is CODEC
2022-06-10 05:54:48.984 D/DBINFO:   SR is SR04 code is CODED
2022-06-10 05:54:48.984 D/DBINFO:   SR is SR05 code is CODEE
2022-06-10 05:54:48.984 D/DBINFO: Related SR's are:-
2022-06-10 05:54:48.984 D/DBINFO:   SR is SR01 code is CODEA ID is 6 related to (child of) CR with an ID of 3
2022-06-10 05:54:48.984 D/DBINFO:   SR is SR02 code is CODEB ID is 7 related to (child of) CR with an ID of 3
2022-06-10 05:54:48.984 D/DBINFO:   SR is SR03 code is CODEC ID is 8 related to (child of) CR with an ID of 3
2022-06-10 05:54:48.984 D/DBINFO:   SR is SR04 code is CODED ID is 9 related to (child of) CR with an ID of 3
2022-06-10 05:54:48.984 D/DBINFO:   SR is SR05 code is CODEE ID is 10 related to (child of) CR with an ID of 3
```

- i.e. the expected result (3 SRs for the first CR, 2 SRs for the second CR and 5 SRs for the third CR **for BOTH methods**)

The actual data stored:-

CRTable has 3 rows :-

[image]

- As can be seen the **values** has the List of SubResults (as a SubResultsList). The disadvantage would be querying the data, say if you wanted just the CRs that had a specific SR code you can't just say WHERE values = 'CODEE', you might get away with WHERE values LIKE '%CODEE%' (but that's inefficient as it requires a Full Table Scan). Also as can be seen there is a lot of BLOAT stored due to the JSON syntax and naming.

SRTable has a row per related SR so 10 rows:-

[image]

- far less data is stored
- searches would like be via index (SQLite Query Optimizer will do it's business)
- the SELECT SQL can be more complicated (especially when Room's conveniences aren't suitable e.g. the query in the example uses subqueries built by Room to get the related SR's rows and that is for ALL related (hence the @Transaction).)

Comment: thank you for your answer! I really appreciate the effort you put into it. But sadly, the answer kind of misses the point of the question. I already store the data in the database, but having problems retrieving it as my code was about the `get..()` functions in Dao with `@RawQuery`…the missing detail, which I admit, I should’ve made more clear, was that the columns that go into the `List<>`, are not in an `Entity` (so no `Relation`), but partly aggregated and partly from an FTS5 index (which room doesn’t support). Sorry I made you spent so much time on this!

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't solve my problem, but found a workaround using multimap as described [in the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/accessing-data#multimap), ie. in this case returning a `Map<CustomResult, List<SubResult>>`:

The main class holding the `List<>` goes like:

```
data class CustomResult(
    val count: Int,
    val name: String,
) {
    @Ignore
    var values: List<SubResult> = emptyList() // note: `var` instead of `val`
}
```

The Dao functions then go like this:

```
// now returning a Map<>
@RawQuery
abstract fun getCustomResultRaw(query: SimpleSQLiteQuery): Map<CustomResult, List<SubResult>>

// maps the Map<> to a List<> 
fun getCustomResult(): List<CustomResult> {
    val params = emptyArray<Any>()
    val query = "SELECT ..... "
    val resultMap = getCustomResultRaw(SimpleSQLiteQuery(query, params))
    return resultMap.map { e ->
        CustomResult(
            count = e.key.count,
            name = e.key.name,
        ).apply {
            values = e.value
        }
    }
```

}